How can I transfer /home to new SSD while keeping a system on new computer?
I have one SSD and one HDD partitioned as this image:

Basically, root the in SSD, and /home in the HDD.
I am going to buy a new computer with one new 2TB SSD. (Major upgrade: i7-12700K -> i9-14600K, DDR4 64GB -> DDR5 192GB, new motherboard)
What I want to do is:

Transfer of current Ubuntu system and programs (especially Docker!!)
Change /home directory from current HDD to new SSD: I want to put my home directory in SSD, and just mount HDD as archive (ex: /home/user/archive/(previous home directory)).

My current plan:

Install the old SSD, HDD, and the new SSD simultaneously and boot.
Set a new home directory in new SSD (although I don't know the exact process..) and transfer all folders with the format /home/user/.(FOLDER_NAME) as .dropbox, .cursor-server, .vscode, and .ssh from HDD to a new SSD. (I'm not sure if it's a good idea.)

Can you validate whether my current plan would work or not? Do I need to format the SSD and install Ubuntu again?

You've provided no Ubuntu product/release details; so we'd be mostly guessing (having few specifics, about your Ubuntu system or your hardware).  Myself I'd just install hardware & boot a Ubuntu system off live media; ensure all drives are working, then copy your wanted directories to the new device as you want, then adjust your current file-system table to achieve what you want & keep it matching your machine firmware settings (ie. BIOS). Boot normally; if it looks good; you can decide to keep the prior original (which maybe shadowed or other depending on what you did) or delete

Not really any different than this. Create partition(s) your want, be sure to initialize drive as gpt first and rsync /home over. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions
Move Home &
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2455822&p=14010437#post14010437  I actually prefer to keep /home and all other / (root) folders in fastest drive, but then if not room, have large data partition and link folders back into /home.

With the disks installed:
Install gparted, if not installed, and start it:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install --reinstall gparted
sudo apt gparted

From Gparted, select the new SSD and create partitions similar to those of the old SSD and HDD, possibly larger, with the same file system.
Then, position yourself in each partition, one by one, copy it from the original and paste it into the new one.
Once the process is finished, the changes have been applied, disconnect the old disks and try to boot from the new one.
